# Hibernate creating Entity Primary Key Id Negative

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

After upgrading to Spring Boot 2.7.7, which is dependent on Hibernate 5.6.14, Entities that are configured with Sequence Generator, new records started with negative ids?

For tables with records already in the database, sequence continues to work fine. The tables are using a postgres sequence to increase by 50, but first id is generating as -47, then -46 and so on. This must be a divide by zero issue, because it doesn't happen on records id with a pre-existing value greater than zero.

Very interesting issue to find, I only noticed because fresh db with unit testing.. Seems Hibernate had issue with this in the past but many years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I'ved determined that Spring Boot dependence on Hibernate 5.6.14 must be downgraded to 5.6.7.Final to resolve the issue. I added a implementation in gradle dependence section.

implementation("org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.6.7.Final")